# How to properly load a library with multiple files from source?

Tags: python, import

I downloaded a Python library from Github that contains multiple files. In the `__init__.py` **none** of these files are imported like `from .xyz import xyz_class`. So I thought the user probably expected to load all required classes directly. However when I tried this with one of the classes it was not able to import it properly, as it misses other classes from this library. What feels odd for me is that the beginning of this class looks like

```
from copy import deepcopy
from collections import OrderedDict
from fields import Fields
```

where `fields.py` is one of the files in the folder of the library. I would have thought this file should be imported using `from .fields import Fields`, but as the dot is missing in several other imports as well I don't think the creator did this unintentionally. So now I am wondering how can I import these classes as the library intents without the `.` or do I need to add it?

Comment: Does the import fail? Isn't the dot needed when using directory names and not module/file names?

Comment: You don't need the `.` prefix because `fields.py` is in the same folder as the `__init__.py`.

Comment: Hi @LukaMesaric yes the import fails with `No module named 'fields'`. This is exactly what I thought, but I am confused how the author of the library intended the use without the dot. Is it somehow possible to "source " all files of the library so that I don't need the dot?

Comment: @Axel Is `fields.py` in the same folder as `__init__.py`? What library are you trying to use?

Comment: Hi @martineau However this doesn't work as the import fails. And for some reason the author of the package for some reason imported some other files using the dot. Do I need to do something special to make this work without the dot?

Comment: @LukaMesaric Yes `fields.py` is in the same folder as `__init__.py`. The library is https://github.com/ladybug-tools/butterfly/tree/master/butterfly.

Comment: Axel: Didn't you say that the `from fields import Fields` was working in your question?

Comment: No it only works with a dot for me. Without a dot the import fails.

Comment: In `butterfly/case.py` `from .fields import Field` is used, but in `butterfly/boundarycondition.py` they have `from fields import Field`, and all files are in the same directory. I am not sure why it would not work nor why someone would do something like that. Can't you just fix that in your version? The library is not actively maintained anyways.

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify. I am able to import the library using `import butterfly as bf`, but when I try to use some of the classes they fail because they try to import classes without the dot.

Comment: @LukaMesaric Yes I can fix this. I just wanted to make sure that it is okay to use the dot for all imports.

Comment: If you add the dot and it works, then it works :)